# Error using package 'xlsx' in dockerized shiny app

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I want to dockerize a shiny app which makes use of the package `xlsx`. A simplified version of the app is posted below. It works fine with most of the packages but for `xlsx` I get an error:

`Error in library(xlsx) : there is no package called ‘xlsx’`

How can I make this work?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rocker/r-base:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libmysqlclient-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks/shiny
# Download and install library
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'xlsx'))"
# copy the app to the image 
COPY ./ ./app
# make all app files readable (solves issue when dev in Windows, but building in Ubuntu)
#RUN chmod -R 755 ./
EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Eruption Wait Times"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 5,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 25)
      ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "blue", border = "blue4", main = "Wait Times Histogram", xlab = "Minutes to next eruption")
  })
})
```

**Building Dockerfile**

```
docker build -t faithful_docker .
```

**Run Dockerfile**

```
docker run -p 3838:3838 faithful_docker
```

Comment: There was likely an error during installation (`docker build`) that you missed. I don't think the rocker images come with `java`, so since `xlsx` imports `rJava`, it should fail during installation. Options: extend your `Dockerfile` to include some compatible variant of Java, or switch to a non-java-dependent package (e.g., `openxlsx`, `readxl`, `tidyxl`).

Comment: `extend your Dockerfile to include some compatible variant of Java` - How can I do this?

Comment: `apt-get install whichever-java-you-prefer`, there are several ways one can go about it. Many are found with a straight-forward web-search [`ubuntu install java`](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+install+java), from there just bake it into the Dockerfile itself.